# PHP How to regex preg_match date from html page

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to fetch date from these html tags via regex preg_match

```
<span>User Signup Date: </span><span class="normal">Aug 24, 2015</span>
```

I just want to fetch only date Aug 24, 2015, every HTML page contain different dates. but all HTML pages contain same

```
<span>User Signup Date: </span><span class="normal">
```

HTML tag before date.

Please tell me what regex formula i have to use ?

```
 Note: HTML page contain many other <span class="normal"> HTML tags.
 So you must have to fetch date from this unique HTML tag 
 which contain <span>User Signup Date: </span> 
 BEFORE <span class="normal">
```

Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<span>User Signup Date: <\/span>.*(?:<span class="date">)([^\<]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/iG6fL8/2

Hope this helps.

Comment: i update question so Please read question again and update your answer here thanks